# Override Protected Function in magento 2

Tags: magento2

**Abc\Tax\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector" type="Abc\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector" />
</config>
```

**Abc\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector.php**

```
<?php
  namespace Abc\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote;
  use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface;
  use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address as QuoteAddress;
 class CommonTaxCollector extends    Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector
{
protected function processProductItems(
    ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
    array $itemTaxDetails,
    QuoteAddress\Total $total
) {
    $store = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress()->getQuote()->getStore();
     ........

    $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 10);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 10);

   ......
    return parent::processProductItems($shippingAssignment,$itemTaxDetails,$total);
}
```

}

Tax changes is not working How can i do this?

Comment: Can you provide the complete path of how you placed of your files for the model and di.xml for your custom module ?

Comment: @AtishGoswami see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to overwrite wrong class. **CommonTaxCollector** class is the parent class of Tax, Subtotal, Shipping total class. All class extend from **CommonTaxCollector**, So if you need any overwrite any method then you need to overwrite Tax, Subtotal, Shipping. In your case you try to overwrite Tax class.

So your di.xml [**Abc/Tax/etc/frontend/di.xml**] looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax" type="Abc\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax" />
</config>
```

And class[**Abc/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php**] looks like

```
namespace Abc\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address as QuoteAddress;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface;

class Tax extends \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax
{
    /**
     * Process product items in the quote.
     * Set the following aggregated values in the quote object:
     * subtotal, subtotalInclTax, tax, discount_tax_compensation,
     *
     * @param ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param array $itemTaxDetails
     * @param QuoteAddress\Total $total
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function processProductItems(
        ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        array $itemTaxDetails,
        QuoteAddress\Total $total
    ) {
        // add your code here

        // call original method
        return parent::processProductItems($shippingAssignment, $itemTaxDetails, $total);
    }
}
```

Comment: The tax is not updated in the `New Invoice` page.
The `Grand Total` is not with the proper tax. Any suggestion?

Comment: @iamkdev which version you have tried. Please post a new question with your need.

Comment: What about private methods? How can we override?

Comment: @SohelRana i need to apply tax based on product attribute rather than shipping address can you please guide me how to do this?