# magento 2 rewrite model is not working

Tags: magento-2.1, override-model

I am using magento 2.1.5 I want to rewrite `Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector` model but it is not working.

my module `di.xml` at `vendor\module\etc\frontend\di.xml` code as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector" />
</config>
```

Module file `Vendor\Module\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector` code as below

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Sales\Total\Quote;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory as CustomerAddressFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface as CustomerAddress;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory as CustomerAddressRegionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address as QuoteAddress;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxClassKeyInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxClassKeyInterface;
use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxDetailsInterface;
use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxDetailsItemInterface;
use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface;

/**
 * Tax totals calculation model
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class CommonTaxCollector extends \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector
{
    /**#@+
     * Constants defined for type of items
     */
    const ITEM_TYPE_SHIPPING = 'shipping';
    const ITEM_TYPE_PRODUCT = 'product';
    /**#@-*/

    /**
     * Constant for shipping item code
     */
    const ITEM_CODE_SHIPPING = 'shipping';

    /**#@+
     * Constants for array keys
     */
    const KEY_ITEM = 'item';
    const KEY_BASE_ITEM = 'base_item';
    /**#@-*/

    /**#@+
     * Constants for fields in associated taxables array
     */
    const KEY_ASSOCIATED_TAXABLE_TYPE = 'type';
    const KEY_ASSOCIATED_TAXABLE_CODE = 'code';
    const KEY_ASSOCIATED_TAXABLE_UNIT_PRICE = 'unit_price';
    const KEY_ASSOCIATED_TAXABLE_BASE_UNIT_PRICE = 'base_unit_price';
    const KEY_ASSOCIATED_TAXABLE_QUANTITY = 'quantity';
    const KEY_ASSOCIATED_TAXABLE_TAX_CLASS_ID = 'tax_class_id';
    const KEY_ASSOCIATED_TAXABLE_PRICE_INCLUDES_TAX = 'price_includes_tax';
    const KEY_ASSOCIATED_TAXABLE_ASSOCIATION_ITEM_CODE = 'associated_item_code';
    /**#@-*/

    /**
     * When an extra taxable item is associated with quote and not with an item, this value
     * is used as associated item code
     */
    const ASSOCIATION_ITEM_CODE_FOR_QUOTE = 'quote';

    /**#@+
     * Constants for fields in tax details for associated taxable items
     */
    const KEY_TAX_DETAILS_TYPE = 'type';
    const KEY_TAX_DETAILS_CODE = 'code';
    const KEY_TAX_DETAILS_PRICE_EXCL_TAX = 'price_excl_tax';
    const KEY_TAX_DETAILS_BASE_PRICE_EXCL_TAX = 'base_price_excl_tax';
    const KEY_TAX_DETAILS_PRICE_INCL_TAX = 'price_incl_tax';
    const KEY_TAX_DETAILS_BASE_PRICE_INCL_TAX = 'base_price_incl_tax';
    const KEY_TAX_DETAILS_ROW_TOTAL = 'row_total_excl_tax';
    const KEY_TAX_DETAILS_BASE_ROW_TOTAL = 'base_row_total_excl_tax';
    const KEY_TAX_DETAILS_ROW_TOTAL_INCL_TAX = 'row_total_incl_tax';
    const KEY_TAX_DETAILS_BASE_ROW_TOTAL_INCL_TAX = 'base_row_total_incl_tax';
    const KEY_TAX_DETAILS_TAX_PERCENT = 'tax_percent';
    const KEY_TAX_DETAILS_ROW_TAX = 'row_tax';
    const KEY_TAX_DETAILS_BASE_ROW_TAX = 'base_row_tax';
    const KEY_TAX_DETAILS_APPLIED_TAXES = 'applied_taxes';
    /**#@-*/

    /**
     * Tax configuration object
     *
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Model\Config
     */
    protected $_config;

    /**
     * Counter that is used to construct temporary ids for taxable items
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $counter = 0;

    /**
     * Tax calculation service, the collector will call the service which performs the actual calculation
     *
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface
     */
    protected $taxCalculationService;

    /**
     * Factory to create QuoteDetails as input to tax calculation service
     *
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $quoteDetailsDataObjectFactory;

    /**
     * @var CustomerAddressFactory
     */
    protected $customerAddressFactory;

    /**
     * @var CustomerAddressRegionFactory
     */
    protected $customerAddressRegionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxClassKeyInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $quoteDetailsItemDataObjectFactory;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface $taxCalculationService
     * @param QuoteDetailsInterfaceFactory $quoteDetailsDataObjectFactory
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterfaceFactory $quoteDetailsItemDataObjectFactory
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxClassKeyInterfaceFactory $taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory
     * @param CustomerAddressFactory $customerAddressFactory
     * @param CustomerAddressRegionFactory $customerAddressRegionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig,
        \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface $taxCalculationService,
        \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsInterfaceFactory $quoteDetailsDataObjectFactory,
        \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterfaceFactory $quoteDetailsItemDataObjectFactory,
        \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxClassKeyInterfaceFactory $taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory,
        CustomerAddressFactory $customerAddressFactory,
        CustomerAddressRegionFactory $customerAddressRegionFactory
    ) {

        $this->taxCalculationService = $taxCalculationService;
        $this->quoteDetailsDataObjectFactory = $quoteDetailsDataObjectFactory;
        $this->_config = $taxConfig;
        $this->taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory = $taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory;
        $this->quoteDetailsItemDataObjectFactory = $quoteDetailsItemDataObjectFactory;
        $this->customerAddressFactory = $customerAddressFactory;
        $this->customerAddressRegionFactory = $customerAddressRegionFactory;

        parent::__construct(
            $taxCalculationService,
            $quoteDetailsDataObjectFactory,
            $taxConfig,
            $taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory,
            $quoteDetailsItemDataObjectFactory,
            $customerAddressFactory,
            $customerAddressRegionFactory
        );
    }



    /**
     * Map an item to item data object
     *
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterfaceFactory $itemDataObjectFactory
     * @param AbstractItem $item
     * @param bool $priceIncludesTax
     * @param bool $useBaseCurrency
     * @param string $parentCode
     * @return \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface
     */
    public function mapItem(
        \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterfaceFactory $itemDataObjectFactory,
        AbstractItem $item,
        $priceIncludesTax,
        $useBaseCurrency,
        $parentCode = null
    ) { 
        if (!$item->getTaxCalculationItemId()) {
            $sequence = 'sequence-' . $this->getNextIncrement();
            $item->setTaxCalculationItemId($sequence);
        }
        /** @var \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface $itemDataObject */
        $itemDataObject = $itemDataObjectFactory->create();
        $itemDataObject->setCode($item->getTaxCalculationItemId())
            ->setQuantity($item->getQty())
            ->setTaxClassKey(
                $this->taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory->create()
                    ->setType(TaxClassKeyInterface::TYPE_ID)
                    ->setValue($item->getProduct()->getTaxClassId())
            )
            ->setIsTaxIncluded($priceIncludesTax)
            ->setType(self::ITEM_TYPE_PRODUCT);

        if ($useBaseCurrency) {
            if (!$item->getBaseTaxCalculationPrice()) {
                $item->setBaseTaxCalculationPrice($item->getBaseCalculationPriceOriginal());
            }
            $itemDataObject->setUnitPrice($item->getBaseTaxCalculationPrice())
                ->setDiscountAmount($item->getBaseDiscountAmount());
        } else {
            if (!$item->getTaxCalculationPrice()) {
                $item->setTaxCalculationPrice($item->getCalculationPriceOriginal());
            }
            $itemDataObject->setUnitPrice($item->getTaxCalculationPrice())
                ->setDiscountAmount($item->getDiscountAmount());
        }

        $itemDataObject->setParentCode($parentCode);

        return $itemDataObject;
    }


}
```

Can anyone please help me how to override it

Comment: Have you faced any error? are you able to call model or not?

Answer (score 1):

Change Path of your `di.xml`

from

`vendor\module\etc\frontend\di.xm`

to

`vendor\module\etc\di.xm`

You override the wrong class for tax changes, You need to override the child class of CommonTaxCollector

Use this :

```
<preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax" />
```

For reference you may check this : [Override Protected Function in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127702/override-protected-function-in-magento-2)

Comment: in both path i have placed it one by one but it is not working

Comment: Also in function i put exit but it is not working

Comment: put exit on 1st line of the class

Comment: i have done that thing as well just after class start i have placed exit but it is not working

Comment: Let me try this ... on which page you are testing(Frontend page)?

Comment: when you add product to cart it will effect

Comment: Answer Updated.

Comment: but i want to rewrite mapItem function in that class

Comment: then instead of preference try to override function using plugin >> aftermapItem()

Answer (score 0):

Change Path of your di.xml from vendor\module\etc\frontend\di.xm to vendor\module\etc\di.xml

then after remove var/cache, var/di, var/generation and var/view_proceed

Hope that will help you.

Comment: thanks for your answer i have done all things but it is not working

Comment: have you convert your xml to utf-8

Comment: that is not the problem all file are working fine but model rewrite is not working